# How to capitalize Xcode, Git, git, and HEAD

Tags: xcode, git

Sorry if this is not directly related to the programming.

What is the proper (official spelling of the words "GIT HEAD" and "XCODE"?

I know the latter used to be spelled "XCode", but now it seems "Xcode" is used.

The reason for question is: I am doing a lot of postings on forums and I want to make everything right.

Comment: For Xcode it's always been Xcode, but people often seem to want to spell it XCode for some reason (even though the application name is staring them right in the face!).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Xcode has always been “Xcode” with a capital “X” and a lower-case “c”. Here's [the press release](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2003/06/23Apple-Introduces-Xcode-the-Fastest-Way-to-Create-Mac-OS-X-Applications/) dated June 23, 2003 announcing the first release of Xcode. <strike>Here's [a video of Steve Jobs introducing Xcode 1.0 at WWDC 2003](https://youtu.be/3S0HlCgfNeM?t=59m13s), and it says “Xcode” on the slide.</strike> (Youtube took down the video.)

“Git”, when referring to the system, is a proper noun and is therefore, by English language convention, spelled “Git” with a capital “G”. Example sentence from the [Git User Manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#_git_user_manual):

> It will be useful to have a Git repository to experiment with as you read this manual.

The command-line program that provides access to the system is “git” with a lower-case “g”, because all-lowercase is the historic convention for Unix commands. If your filesystem is case-insensitive (which is the default on OS X), you can sometimes get away with capitalizing some or all of its letters, but it's a bad idea to make that a habit.

[The currently-checked out commit](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#def_HEAD) in Git is spelled “HEAD” in all capitals, because that string is embedded in the git source code in many places. [Example:](https://github.com/git/git/blob/edc2f715bd2d18566045ed1e8eadd808cedd2903/refs.c#L1090)

> ```
> if (resolve_gitlink_ref(submodule, "HEAD", oid.hash) == 0)
> ```

You can sometimes get away with not capitalizing some or all of the letters if your filesystem is case-insensitive (which is the default on OS X), but it's a bad idea to make that a habit.

Comment: Let me restate a piece of my comment to another answer. The real reason to always spell "HEAD" is that Git "wants" it to be all-uppercase. The fact it *currently* stores *some* of its refs (which are not packed) on the filesystem and hence on NTFS and HFS+ one can use `git show head` hoping for it to work, this is just an implementation detail, [and it can change at least as an option](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/285604/focus=286103).

Comment: Otherwise +1 for being definitive and backing your statements with references; well done!

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate that Git would *never* be spelled GIT, consider Git 2.28 (Q3 2020) and its doc updates.

See [commit 788db14](https://github.com/git/git/commit/788db145c714a6aa4db912579df7fcd44f6e70d0) (07 Jun 2020) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 653a351](https://github.com/git/git/commit/653a3514cc7da856e265fe21711e7ef7b1e183f2), 18 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`t/README`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/788db145c714a6aa4db912579df7fcd44f6e70d0): avoid poor-man's small caps GIT
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> In [48a8c26c62](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48a8c26c625a4d3631c4f614bceb38933e741408) ("`Documentation`: avoid poor-man's small caps GIT", 2013-01-21, Git v1.8.2-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e34c7e2b51c02a761a034b877b852dc0dbccf101)), the documentation was amended to spell Git's name as Git when talking about the system as a whole.
> However, `t/README` was skipped over when the treatment was applied.
>
> Bring `t/README` into conformance with the `CodingGuidelines` by casing "Git" properly.
>
> While we're at it, fix a small typo. Change "the git internal" to "the Git internals".

"`git`" is reserved for commands. Git for the product. GIT for... nobody.

Answer (score 0):

git HEAD

HEAD is a file in the .git directory that points to the current branch or commit if detached.

git is the name of the executable file (file extension is operating system dependent)

Comment: Two nitpicks. While the executable is named `git`, the name of the project is "Git", so supposedly "Git HEAD" or "Git's HEAD", and `git reset HEAD`. The fact stock Git indeed manages (most of) its refs as plain files is an implementation detail, so it suffices to state that the name of the ref pointing to the baseline commit on which the index and the work tree are based is "HEAD", uppercased.

Answer (score 0):

The official shop page of Xcode writes "Xcode".

As for "git head" I do not think it's particularly important. The Application's name is (again acording to its official website) "Git".
The Git command is "git" and the reference is uppercase "HEAD".

But it's more important to be polite and precise when asking questions on forums than correct casing in product names. :)